# JavaScript Make a non-object variable with properties

Tags: javascript, variables, object, properties

I want to have a variable that has a "main" value but has new properties that can only be used with that variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar="random value";
    myVar.prop1="other value"; //How do I make it so that myVar can have that property, but other strings can't
</script>
```

Comment: A primitive (string, number, boolean, null, undefined) cannot have properties. point.

Comment: The opposite is true too, i.e. something with properties (an object) can't have a "main value", which you can assign without overriding all its properties (doing so would simply make it a primitive string).